# I am having a problem with React Native navigation, which is an Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: 'RNSScreen' was not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, uimanager

I am having a problem with React Native navigation, which is an Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: 'RNSScreen' was not found in the UIManager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiItJ.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bON1Q.png)

i am trying to do stack navigation

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you share a more minimal version of the problem? Best is, if you construct a minimal working example, that can be just copy-pasted and run, So we understand your problem.